# Calculating a plug/balance in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My current table has a few accounts which always have minimal values (example, X & Y for actual and AA, BB, CC & DD for plan) in current table.  Accounts with minimal values can extend beyond these accounts. I need to categorize such accounts into proxy account called "balance" which would always be [final-(abc+def+ghi)](please refer to Expected table). I'm trying it difficult to construct this in SQL using
`sum (case when account not in ('abc','def','ghi')`.

[image: Current tableand Expected results]

Sample dataset here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/114cfe/1

**SQL attempt**

```
select year, month, type,

case when accounts in 'abc' then 'abc'
case when accounts in 'def' then 'def'
case when accounts in 'ghi' then 'ghi'
case when accounts in 'final' then 'final'
else 'balance'
end as account_2
,
(
(case when accounts in ('abc','def','ghi','final') then sum(amount)
else 
(
(case when accounts in ('final') then sum(amount))-
sum(case when accounts in ('abc','def','ghi') then sum(amount) else 0)))
)
```

Comment: @DaleK: attempt updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to split it into two steps. Change the values in one step and group the rows in another.

```
SELECT year, month, type, account_2, SUM(amount) AS amount_2
FROM (
    SELECT year, month, type, amount,
        CASE WHEN accounts IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'final') THEN accounts 
        ELSE 'balance' END AS account_2
    FROM someTable
) AS tmp
GROUP BY year, month, type, account_2
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get this. How would the balance be calculated then?

Comment: @Tony if you add your sample data as formatted text, or even better DDL+DML then people can test whether their solution works (without having to re-type in all your sample data) - its in your own best interests.

Comment: @DaleK; Link updated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/114cfe/1

Comment: @Tony this answer returns the desired results if you try it against your fiddle. As an aside why are you quoting numeric values? There is no need...

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, didn't realize. thank you both!